# Find circle coordinates with points by machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms

I have 5 planes that are parallel to each other.

Some circles collisions with the planes and i have 5 collision points for each circle.

Now how i find the coordinates of each circle with that points by machine learning algorithms? Actually just finding out what points are for one circle solves the problem

Something like this image:
[image: Collisions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you use machine learning here?

Where do you get the training data from?

Also, your result will likely be much less accurate than a least-squares estimation using **statistics**. This clearly is a problem that should be solved *analytical* rather than hoping that maybe (if tou are lucky) the machine learning will provide a sometimes usable result.

1. choose a parameterization of the circles (e.g. center, radius, normal vector)
2. derive the intersection points for such a circle
3. derive a maximum likelihood estimate for the parameters given thr intersection points